# spring: no autowire bean

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to crate a user login page, but I keep getting this error when I run it.
This is the message I get when I launch it in my brower:

> HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet SpringDispatcher threw
>   exception
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Servlet.init() for servlet SpringDispatcher threw exception
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.

StackTrace Error Message:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)`enter code here`
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        ... 31 more

    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet [SpringDispatcher] in web application [/mscproject] threw load() exception
    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4903)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:38 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 16072 ms
    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcher'
    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:40 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
    INFO: FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcher': initialization started
    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:40 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sat Feb 04 07:04:40 GMT 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:40 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Found 5 annotated classes in package [project.mscproject]
    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:41 AM org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext refresh
    WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'session'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    Feb 04, 2017 7:04:41 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'session'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.hibernate.SessionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

pom.xml FILE:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>project</groupId>
        <artifactId>mscproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>

        <name>mscproject</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring core & mvc -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- CGLib for @Configuration -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
                <version>${cglib.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Servlet Spec -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- For database pull -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- mysql connection -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- java standard tag library -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Hibernate dependency -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.4.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>springsource-milestones</id>
                <name>SpringSource Milestones Proxy</name>
                <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/springsource-milestones</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <build>
            <finalName>mscproject</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

WEB.XML FILE

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
        <display-name>mscproject</display-name>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>project.mscproject</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
        </session-config>
    </web-app>
```

CONTEXT CONFIG FILE:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


        <mvc:annotation-driven />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="project.mscproject" />
        <context:annotation-config/>



        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
            <!-- Sets the url to that which was passed to the jdbc driver when connection is created -->
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
            <!-- Sets the username to that which was passed to the jdbc driver when connection is created -->
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
            <!-- Sets the password to that which was passed to the jdbc driver when connection is created -->
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
            <!-- Sets the number of connections created when the pool is initialized -->
            <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
            <!-- Sets the max number of idle connections allowed, if it is greater than this value, the excess idle connections will be destroyed on return to the pool -->
            <property name= "maxTotal" value = "8"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basename" value="messages" />
        </bean>
        <!-- Session Factory Declaraton(This creates a hibernate factory session bean) -->
        <bean id = "SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name = "packagesToScan" value= "project.mscproject.datamodel"/>
        <property name ="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key = "hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key = "hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key = "hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
                <prop key = "use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <!-- <prop key = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
        </bean>

    </beans>
```

DaoImplementation file:

```
 package project.mscproject.daoImpl;
   //import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.SharedSessionContract;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    import project.mscproject.dao.UserDao;
    import project.mscproject.datamodel.Users;

    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

        @Autowired
        SessionFactory session;


        public boolean saveOrUpdate(Users users){
            //The main function of the session is to offer CRUD operation to objects of mapped entity class. 
            session.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(users);
            return true;
        }



        //public List<Users> list(){
        //  return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Users").list();

        //}

        public boolean delete(Users users){

            try{session.getCurrentSession().delete(users);

            }catch (Exception ex){
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
        public Users loginUser(Users users){
            Users use= users;
            Transaction tx=session.openSession().beginTransaction();
            String hql = "from project.mscproject.datamodel.Users as u where u.username =? and u.password =?";
                    try {
                            Query query = ((SharedSessionContract) session).createQuery(hql);
                            query.setParameter(0, users.getUsername());
                            query.setParameter(1, users.getPassword());
                         use = (Users) query.uniqueResult();
                            tx.commit();
                            session.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                tx.rollback();
                                session.close();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return use;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your application does not see Hibernate's SessionFactory object. probably you miss it in the xml/JavaConfig of the beans and the way you load it. 
Provide the configuration part of the beans and the code which autowires the SessionFactory

Answer (score 0):

You did not show how do you load xml configution into spring.
Try to bootstrap it like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource({ "classpath:context-config.xml" })
public class HibernateXmlConfig{
  //...
}
```